# How to add php code to hybrid mobile application on Worklight

Tags: php, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to add a messaging service in the hybrid mobile application using php and I am working with Worklight with Eclipse as the IDE.

In which folder I can add php code?

Comment: from what i read from the documentation, you can't add php to your app

Comment: You need to build some API in PHP and put it on a server. Then you can consume that API in your application.